# What does /r mean in a score?

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music, learning

Does anyone know what the "/r" in this score might mean?

Thank you so much...

[image: unknown Score symbol]

Comment: Need to see more of the score.

Comment: it looks like tr not /r

Comment: It would certainly be useful to know who engraved and/or published the score (to compare other examples of theirs), and indeed what the piece is (to compare other editions of it).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that would be `\r`.

Comment: @shoover  pedant  :-)

Comment: @theonlygusti: _I_ say it looks like an _h_ with some sort of weird tumour.

Answer (score 43):

This is actually **tr**, the notation for "trill," an embellishment (or ornament) on a note where you rapidly alternate between the main pitch and an adjacent pitch.

There are many different types of trills; the style of music (and perhaps editorial notes) will clarify exactly which type is intended.

You can check out more in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trill_(music)).

Comment: Could be, but unconvinced the first letter is 't'.

Comment: Not all t's have the tail at the bottom (or, they might have a tail which is more of a serif).

Comment: @AndrewLeach But it also seems to be missing the cross at the top, which is more significant in the orthography of 't'. If it's supposed to be just the right part of the cross, it's easily mistaken for a serif on the 'r'.

Comment: Mixing a sans-serif "t" with a serifed "r" does look odd, though. The method of printing could affect the appearance of the "t", too; are parts of the "t" missing from a piece of type, for instance?

Answer (score 8):

Definitely a trill. A forward slash would be much taller, narrower and more slanted. Certain fonts leave the tail and the cross off the 't' almost entirely, especially when italic and bold. Below is a comparison of '/r' and 'tr' in a more standard, modern font (on the left) and an older, less common font (on the right).

[image]

Comment: Most likely accurate, but if other 'trills' are in the piece, it'd be good to be able to see them.

Comment: @Tim Yes, definitely!

Comment: Considering typography, I'd say the t should not go lower than the r, but that's what it looks like to me in the scan of OP.